# Not able to retrieve cookie value to set header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, js-cookie

I am trying to get the value stored in cookie as "jwt_access" for setting up the header in my react(react redux toolkit was used) app. No matter how much I try it's seems to impossible to get the token. console.log(token) always says undefined .

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { logOut, setUser } from '../auth/authSlice';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const apiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath : "api",
    baseQuery : fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl : 'http://localhost:5001/api/v1/app/user',
        credentials: 'include',
        prepareHeaders: (headers) =>{
            const token = Cookies.get('jwt_access')
            
            console.log(token)

            if(token){
                headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
            }

            return headers
        }
    }),
    endpoints : (builder) =>({}),
});

export default apiSlice ;
```

I  set token in the browser cookie instead of redux state as I face some problem. It would be great if someone help to solve the problem . Thanks.

Comment: What are the properties on the stored cookie? This might be a simple typo, or it could be a scope/domain issue, or it could be a browser setting.